# Some ticks get lost when increasing the domain, why?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{plotpoints=51}
\begin{document}
\multido{\iAngle=351+1}{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-3)(4,3)
\pstVerb
{
    /smjr 4 def % semi major
    /smnr 3 def % semi minor
    /ecc 1 smnr smjr div 2 exp sub sqrt def % eccentricity
    /coe1 smjr smnr mul 2 div def % coefficient 1
    /coe2 ecc smjr mul 2 div def % coefficient 2
}%
% draw ellipse
\psellipse(!smjr smnr)
% draw Focus
\pnode(!ecc smjr mul 0){Focus}
\qdisk(Focus){2pt}
\pscurvepoints{0}{\iAngle}{smjr t cos mul smnr t sin mul}{P}
\pspolylineticks[metricFunction,Os=0,Ds=.25]{P}
{
    coe1 x smjr div acos DegtoRad mul
    coe2 y mul
    sub
}
{0}{5}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\multido{\i=0+1}{5}{\qdisk(PTick\i){2pt}}
\rput(0,2){\textcolor{red}{\Huge$\iAngle^\circ$}}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When the domain of `\pscurvepoints` approaching `360`, some ticks disappear. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `Ds=0.25`. Change it to `0.1` or whatever you need.
For 5 ticks on the whole ellipse use:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.1,-2.1)(3.1,2.1)
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{0}{Pi dup add}{3*cos(t) | 2*sin(t)}%
\pscurvepoints{0}{Pi dup add}{3*cos(t) | 2*sin(t)}{P}%
\pspolylineticks[ticksize=-2pt 2pt,Ds=3.2]{P}{ ds }{0}{5}%
\multido{\iA=0+1}{5}{\Put{6pt;(PNormal\iA)}(PTick\iA){\tiny \iA}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does not help.

Comment: sure! There will always be some lost when your interval is smaller than the number of ticks. However, I do not really understand what you want to show with this image.

Comment: I just want to get 5 ticks with 0 to 360 domain.

Comment: see my edit ...

Comment: But I want to use my own *metric function* given above.

Comment: `acos` returns only angles between 0 and 180

Comment: So is there any way to fix this issue such as defining a new `Acos` that can produce angle between `0` and `360` based on the  value of `x` and `y` specified in the metric function?

Comment: create your own `/Acos`